# Converting jupyter notebook to pdf, latex equations not displayed correctly

Tags: python, latex, jupyter

I have a python notebook which includes Markdown sections that include equations written in latex.

When I download this as a pdf, the equations might be missing some characters and the $ sign used to enter the latex equation is displayed as follows:

[image]